# could not deduce template argument for 'T'

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

My code is :

```
std::vector<double> Vec;

template<typename T>
void GetObj(VARIANT &vtProp) 
{
    CComSafeArray<T> SafeArray;

    SafeArray.Attach(vtProp.parray);
    ULONG Count = SafeArray.GetCount();
    Vec.resize(Count);
    for(ULONG Index = 0; Index < Count; Index++)
    {
        Vec[Index] = SafeArray[Index];
    }
}
```

while compilation I got the error below:

```
error C2783: 'void __cdecl GetObj(struct tagVARIANT &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T'
```

Kindly suggest me the correct answer

Comment: You will need to call the function like this: `GetObj<TheActualType>(arg);`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is nothing in the function template's signature that allows the compiler to deduce the template type, so you need to be explicit:

```
GetObj<TheActualType>(arg);
```